# Pandas: create new columns with conditions

Tags: python

I'm new to pandas and I do some analysis exercise. I want to create a new column that value is the multiplication from two columns with a condition:
**Calculate Money flow by multiplying Typical Price * Volume, This value will be positive if the ‘Typical Price’ of one day is bigger than the ‘Typical Price’ of the day before. Otherwise, the value will be negative. Following this rule, there will be no ‘Money Flow’ value for the first row as it cannot be compared to the previous day**.

The original data set is as follow:

```
Volume  Typical Price
3509      47.810000
4862      48.406667
1810      49.260000
3824      49.263333
2209      47.386667
4558      45.573333
3832      44.396667
3778      43.750000
1005      44.640000
4047      43.760000
2201      44.383333
2507      45.156667
```

The expected result is to have new columns Money Flow Positive and Negative.

```
Volume  Typical Price   Money Flow Positive    Money Flow Negative
3509      47.810000
4862      48.406667
1810      49.260000
3824      49.263333
2209      47.386667
4558      45.573333
3832      44.396667
3778      43.750000
1005      44.640000
4047      43.760000
2201      44.383333
2507      45.156667
```

The logic that I have in mind is...

```
if Money flow negative than previous Money flow move to Money Flow negative
if Money flow positive than previous Money flow move to Money Flow positive
```

I am not so sure how to create if statement in pandas with the above condition, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if this helps:

```
df['Money flow positive']= np.where(df['Typical Price'].shift() < df['Typical Price'],df['Typical Price']*df['Volume'] , '')
df['Money flow negative']= np.where(df['Typical Price'].shift() >= df['Typical Price'],df['Typical Price']*df['Volume'] , '')
df
```

[image]